# THREE.js - Multiple faces

Tags: three.js

Im trying to give multiple faces to a cube in Three.js using WebGL. Im sure the key lies in the

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 80, 80, 80, 4, 4, 4, materials, true,true,false,true,true,true);
```

but I dont understand how to use the "sides" variables.
Here is my demo:

http://enriquemorenotent.com/demos/cube/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier than I thought!

```
var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { ambient: 0xffffff, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '1.png' ) } ),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { ambient: 0xffffff, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '2.png' ) } ),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { ambient: 0xffffff, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '3.png' ) } ),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { ambient: 0xffffff, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '4.png' ) } ),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { ambient: 0xffffff, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '5.png' ) } ),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { ambient: 0xffffff, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '6.png' ) } )
];

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 80, 80, 80, 3, 3, 3, materials);
cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
```